# Why does my game scene appear white?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am developing a 3d game with OpenGL. When I change one scene to another scene (no matter from a 2d menu scene to a 3d game scene or from a 2d scene to another 2d scene), the second scene just seems white and I don't know why. Any help?

This is my render framework code:

```cpp
//Clear the window with current clearing color
glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
gluOrtho2D(0, 800, 600, 0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

//draw 2d
if (!CurrentStage.IsNull()) 
{
    CurrentStage->Draw(false); 
}
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPopMatrix();

glDisable(GL_DITHER);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

//Post camera to current position.
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
Cameras->Post();

//draw 3d
if (!CurrentStage.IsNull()) 
{
    CurrentStage->Draw(true);
}


glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

SwapBuffers(Core->mhDC);

//Render finish.
Sleep(0);
```

Comment: Does the scene appear white when you draw only the 2D or 3D scenes?  Is it just that the scene appears white when you transition from one to the other?  I just wanted to be sure of what you meant.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem, but I have neither CurrentStage nor Cameras. Without further information i have to make a wild guess that gluOrtho2D was not declared and is thus expected to take Ints which it does not (The ints you gave it would thus not be converted to doubles and interpreting them as doubles would yield very small doubles possibly resulting that anything you draw at "pixel" 0,0 will fill the whole screen). To help us reconstruct the problem please make a http://sscce.org/   specifically telling us what CurrentStage and Cameras is or trying to create the SSCCE without them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing any issues here, although I am mainly a DirectX programmer. I think if you showed all of your initialization, we may be able to help you out. I've seen a lot of strange occurrences when dealing with graphics programming, so it may just be a small error you have when initializing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling any fog elsewhere in your code? That seems to by a common error. 
If you are then try this:

```
    glDisable(GL_FOG);

    //Draw 2d scene here

    glEnable(GL_FOG);
```

If you aren't then you may be initializing something incorrectly.